# neovim cannot autocomplete numpy (omni completion not found)

Tags: python, numpy, autocomplete, neovim

I'm trying to get autocomplete to work, but it doesn't work with numpy. I have a script with numpy imported:

```
import numpy as np
```

and I'm typing `np.`, and nothing shows up. Instead I get an error that says `Omni completion (^O^N^P) Pattern not found`. It does work for the `sys` module, however. Interestingly, typing `np` returns the options `np module [jedi]` and `numpy [B]`.

All the answers I could find online are regarding the python version. But I can verify that neovim sees the right python.

I'm using the `pyenv` python:

```
➜  ~ which python
~/.pyenv/shims/python
➜  ~ python --version
Python 3.11.2
```

Typing `:!which python` also returns the same path.

I have the following plugins:

```
deoplete-jedi
deoplete.nvim
jedi-vim
```

`:checkhealth` shows that the latest `pynvim` is installed.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is specific to Numpy, you should install `numpydoc` using

```
pip install numpydoc
```

See related [Github issue](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi/issues/372#issuecomment-372858394)

However if you cannot autocomplete with any of the site-packages (packages install with pip for example):

- If you've used mason to install jedi, then open

```
~/.local/share/nvim/mason/packages/jedi-language-server/venv/pyvenv.cfg
```

- If you've used mason to install pylsp, then open

```
~/.local/share/nvim/mason/packages/python-lsp-server/venv/pyvenv.cfg
```

- Otherwise it could be located at

```
~/.local/share/nvim/lsp_servers/pylsp/venv/pyvenv.cfg
```

And set

```
include-system-site-packages = true
```